# JS regular expresison add something before bracket

Tags: javascript, regex, gulp

I have the following string:

```
@something {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}
```

I am trying to add `heyaaa` before the closing bracket, for example..

```
@something {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
  heyaaa
}
```

I'm using [gulp string replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-string-replace) to search a css file for `@something` and add the needed `heyaaa` string before the closing bracket.

I tried the following but does not work...

```
.pipe(replace('^(\@something\s*{(?:\n.*)*?\n)}', 'heyaaa'))
```

Other regular expressions work so I know there is nothing wrong with my setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are capturing the part from the start until the last semicolon in a group and after that you are matching the closing curly brace. But to get that back in the replacement you have to refer to the capturing group. What you have matched will not be there because you are replacing what you have matched.

To fix your regex you could capture the last `}` in a group `^(\@something\s*{(?:\n.*)*?\n)(})` and in the replacement refer to those groups.

```js
const regex = /^(\@something\s*{(?:\n.*)*?\n)(})/gm;
const str = `@something {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}`;
const subst = `$1  heyaa\n$2`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
console.log(result);
```

To take the start of the string into account and the indentation of the last line, you could match the first line, then repeat while not looking at a new line followed by a `}`.

You could capture the whitespace characters at the start in a capturing group and refer to that in the replacement to match the indenting for `heyaaa`:

```
^(@[^{]+{\s*(?:(?!\n})(\s+).*\n)*)(})
```

**Pattern explanation**

- `^` Start
- `(` Capture group

  - `@[^{]+{\s*` Match `@`, 1+t imes not `{`. Then match `{` and 0+ times a whitespace char
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `(?!\n})(\s+).*\n` Assert what is on the right is not a newline followed by a `}`. If that is the case, match whole line followed by a new line
  - `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `)` Close capturing group
- `(})` Capture Closing parenthesis
- `$` End

In the replacement you could use the 3 capturing groups:

```
$1$2heyaaa\n$3
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mh6HHb/1/)

Using the callback function, your code might look like:

```
.pipe(replace(/^(@[^{]+{\s*(?:(?!\n})(\s+).*\n)*)(})/, function(_,g1,g2,g3) { 
    return g1 + g2 + "heyaaa\n" + g3; }
    )
)
```

```js
const regex = /^(@[^{]+{\s*(?:(?!\n})(\s+).*\n)*)(})/gm;
const str = `@something {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}`;
const subst = `$1$2heyaaa\n$3`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! In your example it works but for me it replaces the entire `@something { ... }` with `heyaa`.  In my code I am searching a stylesheet from `gulp.src('style.css')`, not using a `const str`

Comment: @CyberJunkie  Did you try `.pipe(replace('^(@[^{]+{\s*(?:(?!\n})(\s+).*\n)*)(})', '$1$2heyaaa\n$3'))`? 

Or else try the callback function:

`.pipe(replace(/^(@[^{]+{\s*(?:(?!\n})(\s+).*\n)*)(})/, function(_,g1,g2,g3) {
            return g1 + g2 + "heyaaa\n" + g3;
        }))`

Comment: I tried `.pipe(replace('^(@[^{]+{\s*(?:(?!\n})(\s+).*\n)*)(})', '$1$2heyaaa\n$3'))` but it does not change anything. Maybe I have to instead search for the first closing bracket `} ` in the css and replace that.. `@something` will always be the first element in my css

Comment: Did you try the callback as well?

Comment: @CyberJunkie Glad it worked for you. I have added the code with the callback to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the second parameter of `replace` function: your code replaces what's matched with `heyaaa` instead of inserting `heyaaa` at the place you want.

You can simply do what follows, referring to `$1` (first *matched group*) in the second parameter (*replacement*):

```js
const input = `@something {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}

@otherthing {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}
`

const regex = /^(\@something+\s*{(?:\n.*)*?\n)}/gm

const result0 = input.replace(regex, 'NEW TEXT TO BE INSERTED') // Original substitution
const result1 = input.replace(regex, '$1  NEW TEXT TO BE INSERTED\n}') // Fixed substitution

console.log(result0) // Original result
console.log(result1) // Fixed result
```

UPDATED: EXPLANATION

I added `m` suffix for multi-line regex match and `g` suffix for multiple matching (without it the reagexp is applied on the first match only).

If you need to add `NEW TEXT TO BE INSERTED` at the end of **each** CSS class, you should change `@something` into `@[^\s]` in the regex (see following snippet).

```js
const input = `@something {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}

@otherthing {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}
`

const regex = /^(\@[^\s]+\s*{(?:\n.*)*?\n)}/gm

const result = input.replace(regex, '$1  NEW TEXT TO BE INSERTED\n}') // Fixed substitution

console.log(result) // Fixed result
```

Comment: I tried but the new code replaces the entire string `@something { ... }` with `$1  NEW TEXT TO BE INSERTED
}` I don't have a `const input`. I am searching and entire css file from `gulp.src('style.css')`

Comment: Ok, right. The regex should be applied to `style.css` by `gulp`, shouldn't it? I used `const input = '...'` in order to provide a siple way to show a running example, but the same approach can be applied to your "real lif" case... what about changing `.pipe(replace('^(\@something\s*{(?:\n.*)*?\n)}', 'heyaaa'))` into `.pipe(replace('^(\@something\s*{(?:\n.*)*?\n)}', '$1 heyaaa \n}'))`?

Comment: You should use: $2 instead of $1, it's the second captured Group, you want to keep.

Comment: @PietroMartinelli it seems to work in your example with the const but in the actual style.css it just replaces everything with `$1  NEW TEXT TO BE INSERTED`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to capture everything before last `}` in a group and in callback function of replace use that captured group along with the value you want.

```js
let str = `@something {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}`

let op = str.replace(/^(@something\s*[\w\W]+)}$/g,function(_,g1){
  return g1 + '  heyya,\n}'
})

console.log(op)
```